# How to format a number to Lac or Crores if it has minus sign before it

Tags: javascript

Converting numbers to [lakhs and crores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system) works on positive numbers only.
Tried converting to string and back however this didn't work for me.
I need to also convert negative numbers e.g. `-330000` should convert to `-3.30 Lac`

```js
function numDifferentiation(val) {
  if (val >= 10000000) {
    val = (val / 10000000).toFixed(2) + ' Cr';
  } else if (val >= 100000) {
    val = (val / 100000).toFixed(2) + ' Lac';
  }
  /*else if(val >= 1000) val = (val/1000).toFixed(2) + ' K';*/
  return val;
}
console.log(numDifferentiation(NaN))
console.log(numDifferentiation(0))

console.log(numDifferentiation(1))
console.log(numDifferentiation(100))
console.log(numDifferentiation(1000))
console.log(numDifferentiation(100000))
console.log(numDifferentiation(10000000))

console.log(numDifferentiation(-1))
console.log(numDifferentiation(-100))
console.log(numDifferentiation(-1000))
console.log(numDifferentiation(-100000))
console.log(numDifferentiation(-10000000))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  /* Make stack overflow console fullscreen */
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use the absolute value, Math.abs(x), along with numeraljs to format

Comment: `numeraljs to format` - why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) to return the absolute value of a number:

```js
function numDifferentiation(value) {
  const val = Math.abs(value)
  if (val >= 10000000) return `${(value / 10000000).toFixed(2)} Cr`
  if (val >= 100000) return `${(value / 100000).toFixed(2)} Lac`
  return value;
}
console.log(numDifferentiation(NaN))
console.log(numDifferentiation(0))

console.log(numDifferentiation(1))
console.log(numDifferentiation(100))
console.log(numDifferentiation(1000))
console.log(numDifferentiation(100000))
console.log(numDifferentiation(10000000))

console.log(numDifferentiation(-1))
console.log(numDifferentiation(-100))
console.log(numDifferentiation(-1000))
console.log(numDifferentiation(-100000))
console.log(numDifferentiation(-10000000))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  /* Make stack overflow console fullscreen */
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: your code loses the sign - you should be using `value = (value / 10000000)` etc ... the absolute value is **only** needed for the if comparison - e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/33nw5jcd/2/

Comment: oh dear @Nidhinkumar - did you even look at the console output on https://jsfiddle.net/33nw5jcd/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try and utilise the [Internationalisation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#parameters) built into browsers:

```js
function numDifferentiation(num, format) {
  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'INR',
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    notation: 'compact',
    compactDisplay: 'long',
  })
  return formatter.format(num)
}

console.log(numDifferentiation(NaN))
console.log(numDifferentiation(0))

console.log(numDifferentiation(1))
console.log(numDifferentiation(100))
console.log(numDifferentiation(1000))
console.log(numDifferentiation(100000))
console.log(numDifferentiation(10000000))

console.log(numDifferentiation(-1))
console.log(numDifferentiation(-100))
console.log(numDifferentiation(-1000))
console.log(numDifferentiation(-100000))
console.log(numDifferentiation(-10000000))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  /* Make stack overflow console fullscreen */
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple logic for Crores (both negative and positive value)

```
let val = (-1096000000 / Math.pow(100, 1 * 3).toFixed(2))/10 + "Cr"
console.log(val)
```

Similarly you can set for lakhs/thousands as well by configuring the values of `Math.pow(a, b*3)`

Answer (score -1):

How to format a number 150000 or 1050000 into Lakh Eg: 1.5 Lakh or 10.5 Lakh in JavaScript
Example 1 : 150000 = 1.50 Lakh
Example 2 : 1050000 = 10.50 Lakh
To convert a number into lakh format in JavaScript, you can divide the number by 100,000 and then append the "Lakh" suffix to it.
Here's an example code snippet to convert a number into lakh format:

```js
function formatNumberToLakh(number) {
  if (typeof number !== 'number') {
    return NaN; // return NaN if the argument is not a number
  }
  return (number / 100000).toFixed(2) + ' Lakh';
}

// Example usage
console.log(formatNumberToLakh(100000)); // output: 1.00 Lakh
console.log(formatNumberToLakh(1000000)); // output: 10.00 Lakh
console.log(formatNumberToLakh('invalid number')); // output: NaN
```

In this example, the 'formatNumberToLakh' function takes a number as an argument, checks if it's a valid number or not, and then divides it by 100,000 and formats it with the 'toFixed' method to display two decimal places. Finally, it appends the "Lakh" suffix to the formatted number and returns the result.