# VueJS: Convert random numbers from backend to Indian numbering system

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, numbers

In a Vuejs app, I am getting random numbers from backend say "`2,20,00000`" or it could be "`123456`". I want to display them as "`2.20 Crores`" or "`1.23 Lac`", based on the number generated from backend.

Ps: Crores and lakhs are part of [Indian numbering system.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a number to Lac or Crores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465219/how-to-format-a-number-to-lac-or-crores-if-it-has-minus-sign-before-it)

Comment: How do I pass the value of my variable in the function parameter, my variable is convertedLeaderboardChips, hence I want to pass convertedLeaderboardChips as parameter in the place of val here in this function  : function numDifferentiation (val) {
  if (val >= 10000000) {
    val = (val / 10000000).toFixed(2) + ' Cr';
  } else if (val >= 100000) {
    val = (val / 100000).toFixed(2) + ' Lac';
  }
  /*else if(val >= 1000) val = (val/1000).toFixed(2) + ' K';*/
  return val;
}.

Comment: Can't say much here, as I don't know what is convertedLeaderboardChips here. Is it a data property, or a prop or something else? Also, I don't know how you are going to call numDifferentiation in your code. In your vue template or in js code inside another method?

Comment: So convertedLeaderboardChips variable will hold the random number that comes form the backend, and the same convertedLeaderboardChips will be used in the Vue template once it is converted in to Crore or Lac by that numDifferentiation function